# dynamic sql sp_executesql works but shoots blanks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, dynamic-sql, sqlcmd

Having some fun with `t-sql` and `sp_executesql` (test output below).  The last piece of the puzzle was the need for `sp_executesql` to have uppercase `N` for the query and definition parameters.

I have a feeling that the input parameter `@cardcodeParm` usage is the problem.

As you can see the first two shots work.  The third works but nothing is returned.

```
5> execute sp_executesql N'select cardcode, cardname from dbo.ocrd where @dummy = @dummy  and cardcode = ''BTG000'' ', N' @dummy int ', @dummy = 1
6> go
cardcode        cardname
--------------- ----------------------------------------
BTG000          HUGRO GmbH

(1 rows affected)
1> execute sp_executesql N'select cardcode, cardname from dbo.ocrd where @dummy = @dummy  and cardcode = ''BTG000'' ', N' @dummy nvarchar(5) ', @dummy = '1'
2> go
cardcode        cardname
--------------- ----------------------------------------
BTG000          HUGRO GmbH

(1 rows affected)
1> execute sp_executesql N'select cardcode, cardname from dbo.ocrd where cardcode = ''@cardcodeParm'' ',
2>     N' @cardcodeParm nvarchar(100) ', @cardcodeParm = 'BTG000';
3> go
cardcode        cardname
--------------- ----------------------------------------
```

I am on the learning curve with t-sql using sql server 2005 with sqlcmd client access.

Comment: Thank you for providing queries, results, and suspected trouble location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need `'` around your variable, so you can omit them, and your line will look like this:

```
execute sp_executesql N'SELECT cardcode, cardname
                        FROM dbo.ocrd
                        WHERE cardcode = @cardcodeParm ',
N' @cardcodeParm nvarchar(100) ', @cardcodeParm = 'BTG000';
```

It will be exactly the same as when you did not have the `'` marks around your `@dummy` variable in the first two successful queries.

Comment: You are right, much appreciated.  So sp_executesql must be programmed do the quoting for string variables.